# Is there some way to use pointers inside C switch statements?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, interpreter, vm-implementation

Usually in a dynamically typed programming language, the object struct has a tag field used to identify the object type.
For example:

```
struct myObject {
    int tag;
    ...
}
```

So it is easy to perform different actions using a switch statement based on the tag field.
For example:

```
switch (obj->tag) {
    case OBJ_INTEGER: ...
    case OBJ_STRING: ...
    case OBJ_FUNC:...
}
```

In my case instead of the int tag field I used a void *isa pointer that points to the class that represents that object. Everything worked fine expect that instead of using an elegant switch statement I am forced to use a series of if/else statements. For example:

```
if (obj->isa == class_integer) {
    ...
} else if (obj->isa == class_string) {
    ...
} else if (obj->isa == class_func) {
    ...
}
```

I know that I can't use pointers inside a C switch statements but I wondering if I can use some clever trick in order to speedup the series of if statements.

Comment: What sort of "speedup"? Isn't your compiler doing that for you already?

Comment: You can't use non-constant expressions as the `case` labels.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I guess OP is already aware of that? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Perhaps he needs a formal description of the problem? Otherwise the answer will be just "No".

Comment: what is class_integer? A constant, an int, A char

Comment: C doesn't have classes.

Comment: A quick but dirty solution is to add an integer `tag` field to the `struct` to which `isa` pointer is pointing. However, this would defeat the purpose of having `isa` pointer in the first place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The beauty of having `isa` pointer in the first place is an ability to dispense with switch statements completely.

Consider a switch:

```
switch (obj->tag) {
    case OBJ_INTEGER: do_something_int(obj); break;
    case OBJ_STRING: do_something_str(obj); break;
    case OBJ_FUNC: do_something_func(obj); break;
}
```

Let's say that `isa` pointer points to some `struct` which you own - say, `struct dyn_type`. Add a function pointer to your `struct`, like this:

```
typedef void (*ProcessPtr)(dyn_obj * obj);

struct dyn_type {
    ... // fields of your current struct
    ProcessPtr process;
};
```

Set `process` field to `do_something_int` for `OBJ_INTEGER`, `do_something_str` for `OBJ_STRING`, etc. Now you can replace `switch` with

```
((struct dyn_type*)obj->isa)->process(obj)
```

Comment: Very soon you will have invented C++. :)

Comment: This is a general OO pattern by the way: If you find yourself using a conditional/switch statement that looks at an object's class/isa, that's a code smell. You should just be calling a method on it in 99% of the cases.